# Are convenience initializers really necessary in Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Lately while reading through the swift Realm documentation I've stumbled upon [this passage](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#limitations-models):

> Custom initializers for Object subclasses: When creating your model
>   Object subclasses, you may sometimes want to add your own custom
>   initialization methods for added convenience.
>
> Due to some present limitations with Swift introspection, these
>   methods cannot be designated initializers for the class. Instead, they
>   need to be marked as convenience initializers using the Swift keyword
>   of the same name

Yet this code works flawlessy (abbreviated)

```
@objcMembers
class UserDatabaseEntity: Object {

    dynamic var height: Int = 0
    dynamic var userId: String = ""

    override public class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "userId"
    }

    init(user: UserEntityProtocol, userId: String) {
        super.init()
        self.height = user.height
        self.userId = userId
    }

    required init() {}
}
```

The model is correctly saved and retrieved by Realm even though it specifies it's own initializer and overrides the required empty init. Could someone with a deeper understanding and knowledge of Realm's underlying implementation explain why the above code works?

Is the documentation not up to date and any issues with using your own designated initializers now gone? Or is something else at play here that allows this to work?

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. I wonder if anything was mentioned in the release notes.

Comment: This is a very good question but unfortunately the Realm team is absent from SO so I don't think there will be an official answer. My guess is that while it works now (a 'feature'), it may not work in the future and/or there will be intermittent results. The Realm docs state *Due to some present limitations* which is vacuous as best so no help there. Is there a use case where you cannot follow the docs and use `convenience init` with `self.init()` as shown?